# How do I get the Balls Achievement in Deus Ex?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

How do I get the Balls achievement? I can't figure this one out. The description is:

> [image: Balls!]

**Seems you like playing with balls, eh?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Find the basketball hoop on the Detroit Streets zone and pick up the basketball from the ground with <kbd>E</kbd>. Aim at the hoop. <kbd>Left click</kbd> to throw. Repeat many times until successful.

This is a throwback achievement to the original Deus Ex where you could play basketball in the very same manner. As far as I can remember, there was a message that showed up when you scored.

In an attempt to hit the basket, try this: position yourself behind the center of the concrete barrier in the back left section of the court. Point straight at the center of the rim, then tilt upwards until you're pointing at the red line around the outside of the backboard. I've be able to consistently make it with this configuration.

Comment: Sign him up for the Knicks!!!

Answer (score 20):

I tried about 15 minutes getting this achievement, but the ball physics are tedious at best in this game, so I decided to go a different route.

**Dunking**.

Given that Jensen can't jump to save his life, I roughed up the hobos for their crates, barrels, and dumpsters, eventually creating a big pile near the hoop. I clambered up, brought the ball directly over the net, and pressed <kbd>e</kbd>, dropping the ball through the hoop and earning the achievement.

[image]

[image]

Oh, sweet success!

Comment: Given that the jump aug gives you a nine-foot jump height, can you use that to dunk directly?

Comment: @jprete - there's only one way to find out! Test it and report back!

Comment: lol at dunking, smart!

Comment: So I tested this a while back: Getting the jump-height aug *will* let you dunk *without* dragging a pile of bins and whatnots into a pile.

Comment: I dunked it too.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is having difficulty with this quest, the easiest way to get the achievement is as follows:

1. Stand as close to the basket as possible, but don't stand under it.
2. While holding the ball, look straight up while facing the basket.
3. Tilt your vision down a little bit, aim for the spot between the two windows on the wall behind the basket.  (I don't have a reticule in my game so I can't be more exact than that)
4. Shoot the ball.  It should go nearly straight up and come back down.  If you aimed right, it'll fall right through the hoop.  Adjust your tilt up or down depending on where it ended up.